# $\frac{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}{8abc}\ge\sqrt[8]{\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}-1\right)}$

Tags: inequality

> **Problem:**  Let $a,b,c>0.$ Prove that: $$\frac{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}{8abc}\ge\sqrt[8]{\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}-1\right)\left(\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{b}-1\right)\left(\frac{c}{a}+\frac{a}{c}-1\right)}$$

I tried to use AM-GM inequality as below: $a+b\ge2\sqrt{ab}; b+c\ge2\sqrt{bc}; c+a\ge2\sqrt{ca}$.

Thus, $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)\ge8abc$. The rest is proving the false inequality: $$\sqrt[8]{\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}-1\right)\left(\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{b}-1\right)\left(\frac{c}{a}+\frac{a}{c}-1\right)}\le1$$. I also assumed that: $abc=1$ to get simple form but it is quite complicated.

Is there better way to deal with problem? Please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $MG\leq MA$, we have
\begin{align*}
\sqrt[8]{\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}-1\right)\left(\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{b}-1\right)\left(\frac{c}{a}+\frac{a}{c}-1\right)}&=\sqrt[8]{\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}-1\right)\cdot\left(\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{b}-1\right)\cdot\left(\frac{c}{a}+\frac{a}{c}-1\right)\cdot\color{red}{1}\cdot\color{red}{1}\cdot\color{red}{1}\cdot\color{red}{1}\cdot\color{red}{1}}\\[2mm]
&\leq\frac{\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}-1\right)+\left(\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{b}-1\right)+\left(\frac{c}{a}+\frac{a}{c}-1\right)+\color{red}{1}+\color{red}{1}+\color{red}{1}+\color{red}{1}+\color{red}{1}}{8}\\[2mm]
&=\frac{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{a}{c}+\color{red}{2}}{8}\\[2mm]
&=\frac{a^2b+ab^2+a^2c+ac^2+b^2c+bc^2+2abc}{8abc}\\[2mm]
&=\frac{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}{8abc}
\end{align*}